# Where can I get my hands on a crowbar?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I'm trying to get my hands on a blasting cap in the Orehole Mine, but I need a crowbar to pry open the crates. I'm assuming it's in the tools floor of the elevator, but the box is locked. How do I get it open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a needle to unlock the toolbox in the tools floor of the elevator.

You can find a needle by searching through a haystack. There are a pair of haystacks in the Boring Springs Horsery shop.